# Frequency Table with Random Values

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a frequency program that will represent a bar diagram (in console code). The problem is I have no idea how exactly to calculate this frequency or how do I exactly then give the bars different heights according to their frequency (trough calculation).

The frequency height is capped at 21, meaning the bars go from 1 to 21, so the max bar height would be for example 21 stars (* as display sign for the bar itself).

A calculation I have so far (although not sure if correct) for frequency is the following, where this array takes the random values generated:

```
for (int j = 0; j < T.Length; j++)
{
    T[j] = (MaxHeight* T[j]) / Ber.GreatestElement(T);
    Console.Write("{0,7}", T[j]);
}
```

This results in values between 0 and 21. Based on the values my bars should give a certain height compared to all the other frequency values. For example, 8000 could have 21 in height where 39 could have 1).

To represent this diagram I used 2 `for` loops to display height and width (keep in mind I only wish to use `using System;` to keep it to the "basics").

```
for (int height= 1; height<= 21; height++)
{
    for (int width= 0; width<= 10; width++)
    {
        if(...??)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,7}", bar); // string bar= ("*");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("{0,7}", empty);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

So far I have an entire field filled with * and the random values generated along with their frequency value (although I have no idea if the freq value is properly calculated). 
I assume I need an `if (...)` in the second `for` but I cannot seem to get further than this.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here - you want us to write the whole program?

Comment: Not really. My question is the height of the bars indicates the relative ratio between the different frequencies For example the highest value can have 21 bars where the second highest value only is 18 bars heigh. Not sure in what direction i should look for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are some bits of your code that aren't really defined for us to analyze, but you could try a basic linear interpolation function to achieve interpolated values along a range (e.g. mapping 0->8000 to 0->21).

```
public static float MapToRange(float valueMeasured, float minMeasured, float maxMeasured, float minMapped, float maxMapped)
{
    float mappedValue = minMapped + ((valueMeasured - minMeasured)/(maxMeasured - minMeasured)) * (maxMapped - minMapped);
    return mappedValue;
}
```

So let's say you measured a minimum frequency of 450, a maximum of 8000, and you want to map all values to a range of 0 to 21. You could call it along the lines of this (assuming your current measurement is, say, 2700):

```
float mappedValue = MapToRange(2700, 450, 8000, 0, 21);
```

This would yield: 0 + ((2700 - 450)/(8000 - 450)) * (21 - 0) = 6.25827815

So cast this value as an int and draw 6 stars.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
sorry I wrote in a hurry and my solution was wrong, bufferz wrote the correct one.

i.e. (in a less generic way)

```
int starsNum = (int)((currentValue - lowestValue)/(highestValue - lowestValue) * 21);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you start with code like this, where T is the array of frequencies:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < T.Length; j++)
    {
        T[j] = (MaxHeight* T[j]) / Ber.GreatestElement(T);
        Console.Write("{0,7}", T[j]);
    }
```

You would want to be able to take this code and represent it ina graph, correct?

To do so, you'll want to capture the largest T value, do a bit of math, then write the appropriate number of stars to the screen:

```
double max = 0.0;
for (int j = 0; j < T.Length; j++)
{
    T[j] = (MaxHeight* T[j]) / Ber.GreatestElement(T);
    if (T[j] > max) max = T[j];
}
```

Now that you have the max value, you can determine the number of stars through a SECOND for loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < T.Length; j++)
{
    int numStars = Convert.ToInt32((max / 21) * T[j]);
    Console.Write("{0,7}", T[j]);
    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(numStars, '*');
}
```

Hope that is what you're looking for.